# Does Spring @DirtiesContext reload Spring context?

Tags: spring, junit4, jmock

I have a test class that looks like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/test-context.xml"})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public abstract class TestClass {
  @Rule @Resource public JUnitRuleMockery jMockContext;

  public void test1() {
    //Expectations and test
  }
  public void test2() {
    //Expectations and test
  }
}
```

and in `test-context.xml` I define the `JUnitRuleMockery` plus several mock objects through a `factory-method`, like

```
<bean id="mockContextFactory" class="MockContextFactory" />

<bean id="jMockContext" factory-bean="mockContextFactory" factory-method="getContext" scope="prototype" />

<bean id="firstMock" factory-bean="mockContextFactory" factory-method="getFirstMock" />

<bean id="secondMock" factory-bean="mockContextFactory" factory-method="getSecondMock" />
```

`MockContextFactory` is

```
public class MockContextFactory
{
  private JUnitRuleMockery jUnitRuleMockery;

  public MockContextFactory() {
    jUnitRuleMockery = new JUnitRuleMockery();
    jUnitRuleMockery.setThreadingPolicy(new Synchroniser());
  }

  public JUnitRuleMockery getContext() {
    return jUnitRuleMockery;
  }

  public FirstMock getFirstMock() {
    return jUnitRuleMockery.mock(FirstMock.class);
  }
  //others getter
}
```

In `TestClass` I have several test methods and, due to the annotations `@DirtiesContext`, I am expecting the Spring context to be reloaded after each test execution (since each test sets expectations on mock objects, I have to reload Spring context every time). See [@DirtiesContext from here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html). However, it appears that the Spring context is not reloaded: in fact, entering in debug mode at the beginning of `test2` (supposedly `test1` has been executed earlier) I can see `jMockContext` still holding expectations, execution list and errors (if any) from `test1`.
So, to end up with few questions, does `@DirtiesContext` really cause Spring context to be reloaded (as I understood from Spring Docs) or did I misunderstand the annotation? In the first case, what am I doing wrong? In the latter case, how can I force Spring context to be reloaded for every test?

**EDIT**, to delimit the problem: I had a code like the sample above running from few days, then today I created a new test in which I added an expectation which failed. Then, I saw all the other tests in the class failing for the same reason (while they where `green` until today). Debugging, I found out that `jMockContext` was never cleared, which means all tests were adding expectations to the same pool: of course, as long as no expectation failed, that was transparent and I did not notice it (`test1` adds and passes few expectations, `test2` takes a not-empty pool of expectations ALREADY passed and adds its own so there was no problem), but I do not like the previous situation and I would like to start each test with no previous set expectations at all.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is my solution. I do not know if this is limited to Spring 3.2 or if it is a general misunderstanding, but simply using `@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)` is not enough to cause the entire Spring context to be reloaded for each test. I had to add also the `DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener` in `@TestExecutionListeners`.
So, in the end, what worked for me was just to change the annotation of my `TestClass` to

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/test-context.xml"})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@TestExecutionListeners({DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
public abstract class TestClass
```

Nothing else has to change.

Comment: Presumably you had more than one test listener present - in this case they will override the default listeners, including the one for dirtying the context, and exempt them from being run.
Probably ``@DirtiesContext @TestExecutionListeners(value = {MyListener.class, OtherListener.class}, mergeMode = MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)`` will do it as well.

Comment: Yoy have saved my day!

Comment: Thank you so much! :)