# "BindException: Address already in use" in Spring with Apache FtpServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I configured an Apache FtpServer as follows:

```
@Component
public class FtpDummyServer {

private FtpServer server;

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws FtpException {
    ..some initialization
    this.server = serverFactory.createServer();
    this.server.start();
}

@PreDestroy
public void stop() {
    this.server.stop();
}
```

Notice that the server is automatically started in the @PostConstruct. I have different tests configured in SpringBoot as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MainApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class ApplicationTestX {
...
}
```

When I run the tests individually, they succeed. However, when I run them together, I get a `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind`. How can I avoid that?

Comment: What is the scope of your FtpDummyServer ? I think that you inject the FtpDummyServer many times in your test, if so try to share one FtpDummyServer for all test cases.

Comment: The FtpDummyServer  has the @Component annotation. This is a singleton per dfault.

Comment: can you post your test cases ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each test, an FtpDummyServer is created. However, @PreDestroy was never called. @DirtiesContext solves the problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at exception stacktrace you will see what address ftp server tries to use. Smth like

> Caused by: org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerConfigurationException: Failed to bind to address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:21, check configuration

It may happen because:

1. Another instance of your app uses address. If so you need to terminate them.
2. Some other process uses address/port. In this case you can reconfigure ftp server to bind to another address.

   ```
   FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();

   ListenerFactory factory = new ListenerFactory();
   factory.setPort(2222); //use alternative port instead of default 21
   serverFactory.addListener("default", factory.createListener());

   server = serverFactory.createServer();
   server.start();
   ```

Use netstat to figure out process id that holds address.

Comment: For each test, an FtpDummyServer is created. However, `@PreDestroy` was never called. `@DirtiesContext` solves the problem.

Comment: @RenéWinkler I somehow missed that it was test

Answer (score 0):

Using @DirtiesContext with @TestExecutionListeners works but dont forget to merge your context with the default ones.
E.g:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@TestExecutionListeners(value = {DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class}, mergeMode = MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MainApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class ApplicationTestX {
...
}
```

Have a look there: [Does Spring @DirtiesContext reload Spring context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239875/does-spring-dirtiescontext-reload-spring-context)